# sorting lists in SQL

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I am currently working on an SQL project and am unsure on what code to use in in order to get a specific output. 
Here is what the output should be " Sort the output in alphabetical borrower name order and then by loan date with the most recent listed first." 
Is anybody able to give me ideas for this? All I need is what type of code would work, and possibly how to use it?

Comment: this seems like a homework question

Comment: What all have you tried? Any half-decent SQL tutorial or book will enable you to answer this

Comment: I've tried "Order by" "Desc" and "ASC." One example ive tried is "order by "tablename" DESC"

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an 'order by' question. At the end of your query put '....order by name, loandate desc'

Comment: would this be after a where clause? or from clause?

Comment: Yes after the where clause at the very end